# How to create dynamic variable to create NULL filter in django db query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am running db query after getting a value from a form in Django. There are many options in the form and hence I want to pass it as variable, but also want to filter null values. 
Passing to values is fine as it takes a string, but I am not able to pass the variable to null filter, unless I mention it. 
How to pass value to null filter as a variable?

```
parameter = 'temperature'
TempData.objects.all().values(parameter).filter(temperature__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple parameters to filter out,

```
parameters = ['temperature', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo_bar']
null_filters = {"{}__isnull".format(param): True for param in parameters}
TempData.objects.all().values(*parameters).filter(**null_filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django Orm can handle `None` So

```
parameter = 'temperature'
TempData.objects.filter(parameter=None)
```

should able to return what you are expecting.

Comment: I tried this: TempData.objects.filter(parameter=None)
It takes parameter as a field and not a variable and returns this error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'parameter' into field. Choices are: ...